# MySQL stored event running from Workbench

Tags: mysql, scheduled-tasks, mysql-workbench

I created a MySQL event and tried to run it from MySQL Workbench. But it doesn't run on scheduled times. How I can check logs to solve problem?

```
CREATE 
EVENT `create_attendance` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-11-10 01:00:00' 
DO BEGIN
-- create attendance
    INSERT INTO attendance (idStudent, idLesson, lessonPrice, date) 
    SELECT student.userid, lessons.idLesson, student.fee, lessons.datePassed 
    FROM student
    Inner JOIN `project_course`.group ON group.idGroup = student.idGroup
    Inner JOIN lessons ON group.idGroup=lessons.idGroup 
    WHERE (lessons.idLesson = 
      ( SELECT MAX(attendance.idLesson)FROM attendance)) AND(lessons.datePassed <=CURDATE());
    END  ;
```

[image: Event Status on workbench]